# Writing a Test class

Tags: java, testing, if-statement

I'm currently on a self learning course and need to write a Test program for the following code and repeat steps by assigning different values to the member field.

```
public class DayTwo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
    public void displayDay() {
        int dayNumber = 1;
        if (dayNumber  == 1) {
            System.out.println("Monday");
        } else if (dayNumber == 2) {
            System.out.println("Tuesday");
        } else if (dayNumber == 3) {
            System.out.println("Wednesday");
        } else if (dayNumber == 4) {
            System.out.println("Thursday");
        } else if (dayNumber == 5) {
            System.out.println("Friday");
        } else if (dayNumber == 6) {
            System.out.println("Saturday");
        } else if (dayNumber == 7) {
            System.out.println("Sunday");
        } else {
            System.out.println(dayNumber + " entered. This is not a valid date.");
        }
    }

}
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Post the question from your course if needed.

Comment: 1. There is no member field. 2. This long chain of if is useless, since dayNumber is always set to 1. The whole method body could be replaced by `System.out.println("Monday");`. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: "You'll often create classes that use if and if/else constructs. For instance, you could create the DateTwo class that uses if/else statements to display the day of the week based on the value of a variable.
To do this you need to code the class to evaluate a numeric field in order to determine the day of the week that corresponds to that number."

Comment: This is the code I have been given. I have been asked to write up a test class for it.

Comment: Make your method take the dayNumber as argument. And make it return the day of the week rather than printing it. Then the method will be easily testable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to purely test the code you have, remove `public static void main(String[] args){}` from DayTwo as it's not needed, and use the following Test class:

```
public class TestDay2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DayTwo example = new DayTwo();
    example.displayDay();
    }
}
```

However this will always print 'Monday' due to dayNumber being hard coded. You'll have to change this to test each if statement as I assume you haven't touched on loops yet.

Comment: Thank you. No, I haven't touched on loops yet but will be soon. I'm assuming that's why everyone is telling me my code is wrong. Haha. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`int dayNumber = 1;` it is hard coded value and will always satisfy the first condition skipping the rest of the statements, instead take input using `Scanner` or `BufferedInputStream`

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int dayNumber = sc.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

First o all, Classes that dont run by themselves dont come with a main method. Another mistake of your code is that it will always print "Monday".
For making a test class

```
public class Test{

  public static void main(String[] args){
     DayTwo dayTwo = new DayTwo();
     dayTwo. displayDay();
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not necessary to move `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this....

```
import java.util.*;

public class DayTwo 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int number,choice=1;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(choice!=0)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the day number: ");
            number=sc.nextInt();
            displayDay(number);
            System.out.println("Press 0 to exit, 1 to continue:");
            choice=sc.nextInt();
        }
     }

    public static void displayDay(int dayNumber) 
    {

    if (dayNumber  == 1) {
        System.out.println("Monday");
        } else if (dayNumber == 2) {
        System.out.println("Tuesday");
        } else if (dayNumber == 3) {
        System.out.println("Wednesday");
        } else if (dayNumber == 4) {
        System.out.println("Thursday");
        } else if (dayNumber == 5) {
        System.out.println("Friday");
        } else if (dayNumber == 6) {
        System.out.println("Saturday");
        } else if (dayNumber == 7) {
        System.out.println("Sunday");
        } else {
        System.out.println(dayNumber + " entered. This is not a valid date.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To *follow the instructions* just cut and paste the `dayNumber` declaration so it is a member field (between `class` declaration and `main` declaration). Then create a `new DayTwo` in `main` and you can assign `dayNumber` to different things and print it.

```
public class DayTwo {

    // now a dayNumber belongs to every DayTwo object
    int dayNumber = 1;

    // main is static and belongs to the DayTwo class
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // make a new DayTwo object
        DayTwo days = new DayTwo();

        // displays Monday
        days.displayDay();

        days.dayNumber = 4;

        // displays Thursday
        days.displayDay();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
            days.dayNumber = i;

            // displays all days
            days.displayDay();
        }
    }

    public void displayDay() {
        if (dayNumber  == 1) {
            System.out.println("Monday");
        } else if (dayNumber == 2) {
            System.out.println("Tuesday");
        } else if (dayNumber == 3) {
            System.out.println("Wednesday");
        } else if (dayNumber == 4) {
            System.out.println("Thursday");
        } else if (dayNumber == 5) {
            System.out.println("Friday");
        } else if (dayNumber == 6) {
            System.out.println("Saturday");
        } else if (dayNumber == 7) {
            System.out.println("Sunday");
        } else {
            System.out.println(dayNumber + " entered. This is not a valid date.");
        }
    }

}
```

You don't need anything more complicated than that.